# Using ggplot2 and facet_grid for continuous and categorical variables together (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, charts

I am trying to make a series of graphs like this:

[image]

I have some mixed categorical and continuous data. I am able to make this series of graphs when there are only categorical variables or when there are only continuous variables. But I am unable to produce this series of graphs when there are both types of variables.

I have created some data below. Is there a way to debug this code so that it produces a series of graphs?

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(gridExtra)
library(tidyr)

/create some data/

var_1 <- rnorm(100,1,4)
var_2 <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7) )
var_3 <- sample( LETTERS[1:5], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.2,0.2,0.2, 0.1) )
cluster <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5) )

/put in a frame/

f <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, cluster)

/convert to factors/

f$var_2 = as.factor(f$var_2)
f$var_3 = as.factor(f$var_3)
f$cluster = as.factor(f$cluster)

/create graphs/

f2 %>% pivot_longer(cols = contains("var"), names_to = "variable") %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = value)) + 
    geom_bar() + geom_density() +
    facet_grid(rows = vars(cluster), 
               cols = vars(variable), 
               scales = "free") + 
    labs(y = "freq", fill = "Var")
```

When I only have categorical variables, the following code works:

```
var_2 <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7) )

var_3 <- sample( LETTERS[1:5], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.2,0.2,0.2, 0.1) )

cluster <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5) )

f <- data.frame(var_2, var_3, cluster)
f$var_2 = as.factor(f$var_2)
f$var_3 = as.factor(f$var_3)
f$cluster = as.factor(f$cluster)

f%>% pivot_longer(cols = contains("var"), names_to = "variable") %>% ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = value)) + geom_bar() + geom_density() +facet_grid(rows = vars(cluster), cols = vars(variable), scales = "free") + labs(y = "freq", fill = "Var")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *is* possible to do entirely within ggplot, but it's pretty hacky. Facets are really a way of showing extra dimensions of the same data set. They are not intended to be a way of arbitrarily stitching different plots together, so an entirely ggplot-based solution requires manipulating your data and the axis labels to produce the *appearance* of stitching plots together.

First, we get the unique levels of the barplot variables as character strings:

```r
levs    <- sort(unique(c(as.character(f$var_2), as.character(f$var_3))))
```

Now, we convert the factors to numbers:

```
f$var_2 <- as.numeric(factor(f$var_2, levs)) + ceiling(max(f$var_1)) + 10
f$var_3 <- as.numeric(factor(f$var_3, levs)) + ceiling(max(f$var_1)) + 10
```

We will now construct the breaks and labels that we will use for our x axis

```
breaks  <- c(pretty(range(f$var_1)), sort(unique(c(f$var_2, f$var_3))))
labs    <- c(pretty(range(f$var_1)), levs)
```

Now we can safely pivot our data frame:

```
f <- pivot_longer(f, cols = c("var_1", "var_2", "var_3"))
```

For our plot, we will use appropriately subsetted groups from the data frame for the density plot and the bar plots. We then facet with free scales and label the x axis with our pre-defined breaks and labels:

```
ggplot(f, aes(x = value)) +
  geom_density(data = subset(f, name == "var_1")) +
  geom_bar(data = subset(f, name != "var_1"), aes(fill = name)) +
  facet_wrap(cluster~name, ncol = 3, scales = "free") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks, labels = labs) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("deepskyblue4", "gold"), guide = guide_none())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I do not think ggplot can handle both continuous and categorical variables in the `y` or `x` **aesthetic**. But there is also an error when mixing them in the `pivot_longer()`.

`` Error: Can't combine `var_1` <double> and `var_2` <character>. ``

My recommendation would be to create separate plots for each metric and then combine the plots. This will give you greater control of each plot. Here is an example using **GGally's** [ggmatrix()](http://ggobi.github.io/ggally/reference/ggmatrix.html). I am sure this is also possible with [gridextra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/index.html).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(tidyr)
library(GGally)

# Generate data
var_1 <- rnorm(100, 1, 4)
var_2 <- sample(LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))
var_3 <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1))
cluster <- sample(LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace = TRUE,prob = c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5))

f <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, cluster)

f$var_2 = as.factor(f$var_2)
f$var_3 = as.factor(f$var_3)
f$cluster = as.factor(f$cluster)

# Create plots for each var
var_1_plot <- f %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = var_1,
             fill = cluster)) +
  geom_density() +
  facet_grid(cluster ~ .,
             scales = "free")
var_2_plot <- f %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = var_2,
             fill = cluster)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(cluster ~ .,
             scales = "free")

var_3_plot <- f %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = var_3,
             fill = cluster)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(cluster ~ .,
             scales = "free")

# Combine all plots
plot_list <- list(var_1_plot, var_2_plot, var_3_plot)
GGally::ggmatrix(
  plots = plot_list,
  nrow = 1,
  ncol = 3,
  xAxisLabels = c("Var 1", "Var 2", "Var 3"),
)
```

[image]